# Can I Get Firmware For My New HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, temperature, firmware, hdd

I have another question. I have yet ANOTHER issue with my iMac. When the late 2009 iMac came out, replaced the internal hdd would make the fans go at full blast. I removed my Seagate ST3500418AS (because it died) and replaced it with a Toshiba DT01ACA050. There were no visible temp. sensors when my dad and I replaced it. The machine was quiet and functional, until it started to run at full blast. The Toshiba HDD previously had Linux Mint, so I thought it was a compatibility issue-  that is, until I install macOS X. The hard drive fan is running at full blast! I know I can control the speed with software, but I want to make it so the fans are always quiet (I dualboot macOS and Linux). They (Apple) started programming the drives with temperature sensor firmware. I would like to know how I might be able to get firmware to fix my Mac. I have another drive shipping in later this week, so I will try that, but it will probably be the same issue. How can I fix this? Thanks!
-Logan

Comment: Why not get one of those [inline thermal sensors](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIDIMACHDD09/)?

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't a temp sensor attached to the hard drive? That's a well-known thing. I'd be surprised if such firmware was available to download.

Comment: An inline sensor costs a bit, and I blew all $70 on my hard drive (I’m 13 and I’ve been saving). And no, there was not a sensor. The drive just came out. The fans are running fine now, I think it just needed some time.